# unchecked call to compare(T,T) as a member of the raw type Comparator

Tags: java, generics, java-8, comparator, raw-types

We are migrating our existing code from Java 1.5 to Java 8, and while compiling with -Xlint, I came across warnings like "unchecked call to `compare(T,T)` as a member of the raw type `Comparator`".

I roughly understand that I need to somehow tell which datatype I'd be passing in to `Comparator`, but I'm using generics so I can pass in different datatypes, so how can I eliminate this warning.

Here's a snippet of my code where I'm seeing this warning:

```
private static void  mergeSort(Object[] source, int[] src,int[] dest,
                                        int low, int high, int off,  Comparator c) {
        int length = high - low;

        for (int i=low; i<high; i++)
                for (int j=i; j>low && c.compare(source[dest[j-1]], source[dest[j]])>0; j--) {
                    int t =  dest[j];
                    dest[j] = dest[j-1];
                    dest[j-1] = t;
                }
            return;
}
```

And, this is being called as:

```
public void setSort( Comparator<T> comparator) {
List<T> currentList = getCurrentList();

        int[] dst = new int[currentList.size()];
        for (int i=0; i< currentList.size(); i++)
            dst[i]=i;
        int [] src = dst.clone();
        mergeSort (currentList.toArray(), src, dst,0, dst.length, 0,  comparator );
}
```

Since I'm already saying `Comparator<T> comparator` in `setSort()` method, why am I still getting the below error?

> ```
> warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compare(T,T) as a member of the
> raw type Comparator  [multiant]               for (int j=i; j>low &&
> c.compare(source[dest[j-1]], source[dest[j]])>0; j--) {
> ```

Comment: So many problems can be avoided by simply not using raw types.  (Add a type parameter to your `Comparator`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have to change the definition of `mergeSort`:

```
public static <T> void mergeSort(Object[] source, int[] src, int[] dest,
        int low, int high, int off, Comparator<T> c) {
```

And than you have to do a cast:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 T[] sourceC = (T[]) source;
```

You know that the array is of type `T` but you can't declare a generic array. But that's ok, since `T` is going to be erased to `Object` at runtime either way.

And the for loop slightly changes to use that:

```
for (int j = i; j > low && c.compare(sourceC[dest[j - 1]], sourceC[dest[j]]) > 0; j--)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This has helped me clear the warning I was seeing.

Comment: You can *declare* a generic array type. You just can't create one. See for example [`<T> void Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting is a warning: it's simply telling you that what you're doing has the potential to cause problems for you if you pass it bad datatypes. This does not mean that you cannot compile and run your program, but it is telling you that you are in danger of crashing your program by sending something which the Comparator.compare() function cannot handle. If you want to really remove this warning, consider finding if the objects which you are passing all inherit an interface or parent class and parametrize the Comparator and the array of objects as that type.